# How to get data from SQL Server database of current date in Asp .Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to get data from a SQL Server database according to current date. In database datetime is stored in this format `2016-07-20 22:05:18.000`

I want data according date filter not time.

So I did this :

```
string startDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00");
string endDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59");
DateTime startDate1 = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
DateTime endDate1 = DateTime.Parse(endDate);

private online_rechargesEntities db = new online_rechargesEntities();

ViewBag.billHistory =  db.tbl_userInfo.Where
(x => x.INSRT_TMSP >= StartDate1 && x.INSRT_TMSP <= EndDate1).ToList();
```

But it is not returning the correct data.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: I don't think that the cause of the problem, but why do you convert dates to strings and back to dates? You can get the start and end of the day like this: `DateTime.Today` and `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1)`.

Comment: But how can i get only date from datetime ?

Comment: You don't get only date. the Today property gives to today's date at midnight (2016-07-24 00:00:00), and adding a day and subtracting a second gives to today's date at 23:59:59.

Comment: Is my query is correct ? Beacuse i could not get accurate data....

Comment: I don't know. How can I know that if you don't even supply sample data?  your syntax seems fine, this where should return records that the `INSRT_TMSP` property has a datetime value that's sometime today. but If it doesn't return any results, and you have such records in your database, then something is wrong...

Comment: You could also do `DateTime.Today` and `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).Date` and change the query to `>=StartDate && <EndDate` avoiding the addseconds bit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no conflict between startDate1, endDate1  and you date-times in your database which is SQL server.

Preferably try to use these new types [DatetimeOffset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netcore-3.1) which takes care of timezone differences.